# set debian system logs timestamp to be like system date

Tags: logging, debian, clock

I am having Debian wheezy,
I had set my system timezone using `dpkg-reconfigure tzdata` to `Asia/jerusalem`
My problem is that the system logs are still using the GMT instead of my system TZ (IDT)
for example here are the last log line from `mail.log` with `tail -100f /var/log/mail.log` I had just sent mail through the system and you can see it.

```
# tail -100f /var/log/mail.log
...
Jul  4 23:35:08 s1 postfix/smtp[22918]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com ...
....

# date
Sat Jul  5 02:35:36 IDT 2014
# hwclock
Sat 05 Jul 2014 02:39:39 AM IDT  -0.786973 seconds
```

as you can see the log time stamp is on GMT while my systme clock is on GMT+3, what can I do to sync it?

Comment: can you please guide me for the command?
Googling gave me `/etc/init.d/syslog restart`, but there is no such file.

Comment: What files that look like the right thing can you find in `/etc/init.d`?

Comment: Thanks for your help.
I had solved it with: `/etc/init.d/rsyslog restart`
and check the logs, it is now accurate

Comment: I added that as an answer so you can accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

syslogd needs to be restarted:

```
/etc/init.d/rsyslog restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Before restart `rsyslog`, I found that my localtime file is wrong, although the command '`date`' get the right time.

```
ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Shanghai /etc/localtime
```

And then restart `rsyslog`, it work.